# Error 500 when I push the button in primefaces

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I´m newbie in JSF, i have a button and i want to use as link but the page is in a subdirectory and I have got this error. How i can solution it? Thx, Sorry I´m learning english.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.primefaces.renderkit.OutcomeTargetRenderer.getTargetURL(OutcomeTargetRenderer.java:80)
    org.primefaces.component.button.ButtonRenderer.buildOnclick(ButtonRenderer.java:93)
    org.primefaces.component.button.ButtonRenderer.encodeMarkup(ButtonRenderer.java:53)
    org.primefaces.component.button.ButtonRenderer.encodeEnd(ButtonRenderer.java:32)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875
```

I have the next code.
**index.xhtml**

```
 <p:button outcome="#{FacesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/pages/menuPrincipal" value="PrincipalCon" title="Go Menu2">
</p:button>

  <p:button outcome="#{FacesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}pages/menuPrincipal" value="PrincipalSin" title="Go Menu2">
 </p:button>

  <p:button outcome="/pages/menuPrincipal" value="SeleccionConBarra" title="Go Menu2">
  </p:button>

  <p:button outcome="/pages/menuPrincipal" value="SeleccionSinBarra" title="Go Menu2">
 </p:button>
```

i have changed outcome by url and it´s not works, Can be app-config.xml or faces-config?

Comment: Is `FacesContext` up there a copy-n-paste error? The correct usage is `facesContext`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your outcome is apparently not right. What about something like this

```
<p:button outcome="/pages/menuPrincipal/SeleccionSinBarra" value="SeleccionSinBarra" title="Go Menu2">
</p:button>
```

Comment: I have changed it by this code but it´s not works. `code`<p:button outcome="pages/menuPrincipal value="SeleccionSinBarra" title="Go Menu2">
</p:button> `code` I have changed it by this code but it´s not works. In all cases, it´s not works :( I have got Error 500 java.lang.NullPointerException
but if i put menuPrincipal in principal directory it´s works.  The code of before (index.xthml) are testing by me :(

Comment: It´s works i have changed face-config.xml i added rules navigation. Thx :)